# Evaluating matrix equation

Tags: linear-algebra

A $2x2$ matrix $M$ satisfies the conditions $$M\begin{bmatrix}
       -8 \\
       1
       \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
       3 \\
       8
       \end{bmatrix}$$

and

$$M\begin{bmatrix}
       1 \\
       5
       \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
       -8 \\
       7
       \end{bmatrix}.$$

Evaluate $$M\begin{bmatrix}
       1 \\
       1
       \end{bmatrix}.$$

What is the question essentially asking? Isn't this just a matrix equation?

Comment: You could formulate it that way. There is a couple of approaches to the problem, all ending up in the same place if done correctly.

Comment: What would be the way to approach?

Comment: the question is that you have to compute the value of $M\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: @Daniel there are 4 free variable namely, $M_{11}, M_{12}, M_{21}$ and $M_{22}$.

Answer (score 3):

We know that

$$M\begin{pmatrix}
       -8 & 1 \\
       1 & 5
       \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
       3 &-8\\
       8 & 7
       \end{pmatrix}.$$
Multiply that equation from right by
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
       -8 & 1 \\
       1 & 5
       \end{pmatrix}^{-1}=\frac{1}{-41}\begin{pmatrix}
       5 & -1 \\
       -1 & -8
       \end{pmatrix}
$$
to get $M$.

Answer (score 3):

Note that the given input vectors form a basis of $\Bbb{R}^2$. So we can express any vector in $\Bbb{R}^2$ in terms of the given vectors such as:
$$\begin{bmatrix}a\\b\end{bmatrix}={\small\left(\frac{b-5a}{41}\right)}\begin{bmatrix}-8\\1\end{bmatrix}+{\small \left(\frac{a+8b}{41}\right)}\begin{bmatrix}1\\5\end{bmatrix}. \tag{1}$$
In particular,
$$\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\end{bmatrix}={\small\frac{-4}{41}}\begin{bmatrix}-8\\1\end{bmatrix}+{\small\frac{9}{41}}\begin{bmatrix}1\\5\end{bmatrix}.$$
Thus
\begin{align*}
M\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\end{bmatrix}& ={\small \frac{-4}{41}}\color{red}{M\begin{bmatrix}-8\\1\end{bmatrix}}+{\small \frac{9}{41}}\color{blue}{M\begin{bmatrix}1\\5\end{bmatrix}}\\
&={\small \frac{-4}{41}}\color{red}{\begin{bmatrix}3\\8\end{bmatrix}}+{\small\frac{9}{41}}\color{blue}{\begin{bmatrix}-8\\7\end{bmatrix}}\\
&=\begin{bmatrix}\frac{-84}{41}\\\frac{31}{41}\end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}

**Generalization:**

In fact, we can answer more generally as to what will $M$ do to any vector in $\Bbb{R}^2$. From equation (1)
\begin{align*}
M\begin{bmatrix}a\\b\end{bmatrix}&={\small\left(\frac{b-5a}{41}\right)}\color{red}{M\begin{bmatrix}-8\\1\end{bmatrix}}+{\small \left(\frac{a+8b}{41}\right)}\color{blue}{M\begin{bmatrix}1\\5\end{bmatrix}}\\
&={\small\left(\frac{b-5a}{41}\right)}\color{red}{\begin{bmatrix}3\\8\end{bmatrix}}+{\small \left(\frac{a+8b}{41}\right)}\color{blue}{\begin{bmatrix}-8\\7\end{bmatrix}}\\
&={\small \frac{1}{41}}\begin{bmatrix}-23a-61b\\-33a+64b\end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}

This also helps us find $M$ as
$$M\begin{bmatrix}a\\b\end{bmatrix}={\small \frac{1}{41}}\begin{bmatrix}-23a-61b\\-33a+64b\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}\frac{-23}{41}&\frac{-61}{41}\\ \frac{-33}{41}&\frac{64}{41}\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}a\\b\end{bmatrix}.$$

Answer (score 0):

If you find two numbers $x,y\mathbb{R}$ such that $x\begin{bmatrix}-8\\1\end{bmatrix}+y\begin{bmatrix}1\\5\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\end{bmatrix}$, then, make a left  multiply by $M$:

$$xM\begin{bmatrix}-8\\1\end{bmatrix}+yM\begin{bmatrix}1\\5\end{bmatrix}=M\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\end{bmatrix}$$
finally,

$$ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~x\begin{bmatrix}3\\8\end{bmatrix}+y \begin{bmatrix}-8\\7\end{bmatrix} = M\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\end{bmatrix}~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\cdots(I)$$

So, all your problem is reduced to $x\begin{bmatrix}-8\\1\end{bmatrix}+y\begin{bmatrix}1\\5\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\end{bmatrix}$

which is equals to

$$\begin{cases} -8x + y & =1\\ x+5y  & = 1\end{cases}
$$

with solution $x=-\frac{4}{41},~y=\frac{9}{41}$. Just reemplace $x,y$ in equation $(I)$.

Comment: Could you elaborate on how did you get from $(I)$ to the reduced form you mentioned?

Comment: its because from premises $M\begin{bmatrix}-8\\1\end{bmatrix} =\begin{bmatrix}3\\8\end{bmatrix} $

Comment: I meant from $x\begin{bmatrix}3\\8\end{bmatrix}+y \begin{bmatrix}-8\\7\end{bmatrix} = M\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\end{bmatrix}$ to $x\begin{bmatrix}-8\\1\end{bmatrix}+y\begin{bmatrix}1\\5\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: just multiply by $M$ to the left , $M(x\begin{bmatrix}-8\\1\end{bmatrix}+...y()) = (Mx\begin{bmatrix}-8\\1\end{bmatrix} + My()...)... = (xM\begin{bmatrix}-8\\1\end{bmatrix} + yM()...)$